# How to handle multiple forms' submission in a custom module by clicking on a link

Tags: forms

I have 2 forms in my custom drupal7 module.
The 1st one (`mymodule_form1_form`) is a normal form with a lot of fields and a submit button at the bottom.
The 2nd one (`mymodule_delete_data_form`) has 1 hidden field and there is no submit button.
There is a link at the end of the 1st form which triggers a javascript logic. The javascript logic submits the 2nd form.

My problem is that I can't catch the submission of the 2nd form. The page reloads, but it doesn't entry into the `mymodule_delete_data_form_submit` function and I can't run the special business logic that removes the data from the database in this case.

The 1st form

```
function mymodule_form1_form($form, &$form_state, $node, $cid)
{
    $form['field1'] = array(
        '#type'       => 'textfield',
        '#title'      => 'Name',
        '#title_display'  => 'invisible',
        '#size'       => 60,
        '#maxlength'  => 128,
        '#required'   => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Name',
        )
    );

    $form['delete_record_link'] = array(
        '#markup'     =>
            "<div class='delete-record'>
                <a href='#' onclick='return false;'>I would like to delete my record...</a>
            </div>",
        '#attributes' => array(
            'class'   => array('additional')
        )
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type'  => 'submit',
        '#title' => filter_xss("Submit"),
        '#value' => "Submit",
        '#title_display' => 'invisible'
    );

    return $form;
}
```

The 2nd form

```
function mymodule_delete_data_form($form, &$form_state, $node, $cid)
{
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_delete_data_form_submit';

    $form['delete_record'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Remove the data from the database',
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 128,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Remove the data from the database',
        ),
        '#value' => "0"
    );

    return $form;
}
```

The submit function of the 1st form (it works like a charm):

```
function mymodule_form1_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    echo "submit function 1<br/>";
    exit();
}
```

The submit function of the 2nd form (it doesn't trigger):

```
function mymodule_delete_data_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    echo "submit function 2<br/>";
    exit();
}
```

The javascript logic that submits the 2nd form, when you click on the link in the 1st form:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var delete_record_field = jQuery("#edit-delete-record");
    var delete_record_link  = jQuery("#mymodule-form1-form .delete-record a");

    delete_record_link.on("click", function() {
        // set the value of the hidden field to 1
        delete_record_field.val("1");

        // submit the form
        jQuery("#mymodule-delete-data-form").submit();
    });
});
```

What is wrong in my code? How can I catch the submission of the 2nd form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal requires a submit button to submit - it uses the value of the submit button to determine which form was submitted.

Add a submit button to your form, and instead of executing $.submit() on your form, execute $.mousedown() on the hidden submit button.

Comment: thank you @Jaypan! This was the solution. I added a submit button to the 2nd form and I hid it by css, because this second form mustn't be visible.